# jQuery popup box is not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a popup box from a div.  My code is below.

Upon successful addition on record the div needs to be shown but its not working.  I have tried `$("#div").html`.

**Script:**

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js "></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#users').submit(function() {
      $('#response').html("<b>Adding...</b>");
      $.post('controller_adduser.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
         $('#response').html("<b>Adding...</b>");

         //// Show div Message box

      }).fail(function() {
         alert( "Posting failed." );
      });
      return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

**DIV:**

```
<div id="remote_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-accessibility"></i> Loading remote path</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body with-padding">
               <p>Added!!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**POPUP MSG BOX**
[image: msgbox]

Comment: Which `div` do you want to show there? Are you talking about the `div` with id "response"?

Comment: @VivekPradhan yes, the `div` is basically a popup box

Comment: Where is the `div` with id "response" in your html? You're probably trying to show the modal dailog with id "remote-modal" and I think you're using bootstrap.

Comment: Where is the #response div in your markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that youre using bootstrap. In order for the modal to show you need to run the `.modal("show")` command. I would try this:
HTML:

```
<div id="remote_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">
                     <i class="icon-accessibility"></i> 
                    <span id="response">Loading remote path</span>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body with-padding">
               <p>Added!!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

JS:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js "></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#users').submit(function() {
      $.post('controller_adduser.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
         $('#remote_modal #response').html("<b>Adding...</b>");
         $('#remote_modal').modal("show");
      }).fail(function() {
         alert( "Posting failed." );
      });
      return false;
   });
});
</script>
```